# Generate dynamic web app structure J2EE

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, code-generation

Is there any Method or API that will help me to generate the structure of dynamic web app in eclipse?
I want to generate the whole structure: /src; /WebContent/WEB-IN,.. and the web.xml.
I am trying to develop an app that takes the Model Class and generates all the basic web app for those Model Class.

Comment: Have you looked at Maven? it has archetypes to create a web based project structure.

Answer (score 3):

That's what M2T-JET was designed for.  It's a template-based generator (think JSP in Eclipse).  Use these tags in the main.jet template:

- ws:project creates an eclipse project with the specified name
- ws:folder creates an eclipse folder with the specified path
- ws:file creates a file with the given path using content derived from applying the input model to a specified .jet template

The input model is usually XML, but there are loaders in JET that can use other sources as models: Eclipse itself, EMF models and - of more interest to you - java source files.  This java loader takes java source, parses it into an AST model and then passes that model on to the main.jet template.

Answer (score 1):

You shoul try this development accelerator 
https://sites.google.com/site/telosystutorial/ 
(different examples with Spring MVC, Spring Data, etc )